# Does $G/H\cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $H\cong \mathbb{Z}^m$ imply that $G\cong \mathbb{Z}^{m+n}$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $H\subseteq G$ a normal subgroup such that $H\cong \mathbb{Z}^m$ holds for some positive integer $m$. Suppose that we know that there exist a non-negative integer $n$ such that $G/H\cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ holds. Do we then necessarily have $G\cong \mathbb{Z}^{m+n}$? If it helps, we may assume that $G$ is Abelian (but I'm not certain if that will help).

I couldn't really find a counterexample to this, but I'm not particularly close to a proof either. I tried to come up with an isomorphism, but how do we even construct a homomorphism from G to $\mathbb{Z}^{m+n}$ that is promising? I was also thinking about whether or not the claim that $G$ is finitely generated is necessary, but this also didn't get me any further. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: The fact that $G$ is abelian is crucial, if not the Heisenberg group could be a counterexample. Its center is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and the abelianization is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  The case $G$ abelian follows immediately from structure theorem for finitely-generated abelian group.  Or if you want to be fancy, you can indeed drop the assumption $G$ or $H$ being finitely generated and appeal to the result

> **Fact**: $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module

to get a splitting of $0\to H\to G\to\mathbb{Z}^n\to 0$.

---

If $G$ is not abelian, the discrete Heisenberg group
$$
H_3(\mathbb{Z}):=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&a&c\\0&1&b\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}: a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
provides a counterexample as @jMdA commented above.

Comment: Thank you very much!